# How to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})$ convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be convex and $\limsup\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(\frac{x}{2})}{f(x)}<\frac{1}{2}$.Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})$ convergence.This is our final exam last term.All I know is that when $n$ is large enough, $f(\frac{1}{2n})\leqslant\frac{1}{2}f(\frac{1}{n})$ holds.But I don't know how to use the convexity of $f(x)$.

Comment: So you're cheating?

Comment: @spinosarus123 last term

Comment: Before taking $f(\frac 1 n)$ to the other side you have to make sure that $f(\frac 1 n)>0$.

Comment: Is it given that $f$ is strictly positive?

Comment: @Martin R Thank you sir,it's not given

Comment: Convexity and the growth condition imply that $f(0)=0$ (as convex functions on $\mathbb{R}$ are continuous). Then we get $$\frac{f(x/2)}{f(x)}=\frac{f(x/2)-f(0)}{f(x)-f(0)} = 2 \frac{\left(\frac{f(x/2)-f(0)}{x/2-0}\right)}{\left(\frac{f(x/2)-f(0)}{x/2-0}\right)}.$$ However, both the denominator and the numerator converge to the rightsided derivative of $f$ at $x=0$. Either the rightsided derivative is equal to zero, or the whole expression converges to $2$ for $x\rightarrow 0^+$ (in which case the function is positive on $[0,\infty)$).

Comment: If $f$ can take both positive and negative values then it is zero somewhere, which means that the expression in the $\limsup$ is not well-defined. So one must assume *something* about the sign of the function.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: $f$ could be zero on an interval $[0, a]$.

Comment: @MartinR I just realized that :( then the condition makes no sense, but the convergence is easy to show :) also this is the only thing that could make the limsup not exist.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Sure. – Anyway, I would prefer it if the author of the question clarifies the exact hypotheses before posting an answer.

Comment: @Martin R Thank you, sir, but our teacher said there was no problem with the conditions, which should be hypothetical...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q$ be a number with $\limsup_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f(x/2)}{f(x)}<q<\frac12$. For the $\limsup$ to even make sense, there must exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $0<x<\epsilon$, we have
$ f(x)\ne 0$ and $\frac{f(x/2)}{f(x)}<q$.
Convex implies continuous. Suppose $f(0)\ne 0$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x/2)}{f(x)}=1$, contradicting $q<\frac12$. We conclude that $f(0)=0$.By convexity,
$$\tag1 f(\tfrac x2)\le\frac{f(x)+f(0)}{2}=\frac12f(x).$$
Note that $f$ has constant sign on $\left]0,\epsilon\right[$.
If $f(x)<0$ for $x$ in that interval, $(1)$ implies $q>\frac{f(x/2)}{f(x)}\ge \frac12$, contradiction. We conclude that $f$ is positive on $\left]0,\epsilon\right[$; moreover, $f$ is strictly increasing on that interval.
But if $f$ is positive, we find in fact that
$$ f(x/2)<qf(x)$$ for all $x\in\left]0,\epsilon\right[$.

Let $a_n=f(\tfrac1n)$. From the above, (possibly ignoiring finitely many initial exceptions) the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is positive and strictly decreasing and
$$ \sum_{n=2N}^{4N-1}a_n= \sum_{n=2}^{2N-1}(a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})\le  \sum_{n=N}^{2N-1}(2a_{2n})<2q\sum_{n=N}^{2N-1}(a_{n}).$$
Conclude.

Comment: Thank you!I have a question,why$\sum_{n=2N}^{4N-1}a_n= \sum_{n=2}^{2N-1}(a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})\le  \sum_{n=N}^{2N-1}(2a_{2n})<2q\sum_{n=N}^{2N-1}(a_{n}).\implies \sum a_n$convergence?